# Curved box into css?

Tags: html, css

Can [this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNqUh.jpg) be created using only css, or at least 90% css with corner pieces, or would it be best to just redesign it?

Comment: CSS3 "border-radius" property can entirely create rounded corners in the design elements, without the need for corner images or the use of multiple div tags. Take a look here [link](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use CSS3:

```
div{
    border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corner on all corners */
}
```

If you want to use a more browser-support friendly method, you can use background images, or a method like that that [Spiffy Corners](http://www.spiffycorners.com/) provides, using small divs to recreate the effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
.panel {
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 Property for webkit design engine used browser */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 Property for Mozilla */
    -o-border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 Property for Opera */
    border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 Property for Modern Browsers */
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: You should really put vendor-prefixed versions above the valid CSS3 entry

Comment: Putting vendor prefixes after the (will-be) standard is terrible practice. You should [absolutely do the reverse](http://css-tricks.com/7361-ordering-css3-properties/).

Comment: ohh i heared about this first time. thanks :)... also changed in answer

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SpiffyCorners](http://www.spiffycorners.com/) for example or [google for css rounded corners](http://google.com?q=css%20rounded%20corners)

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible, see [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

however if you decide to use corner pieces for compatability you can jsut use:

```
<div id="box">
<div style="clear:both;">
  <div id="topleft" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div id="topright" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div style="clear:both;">
  <div id="bottomleft" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div id="bottomright" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

entirely with css. not exact, but very similar http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/EBfbZ/